# Duplicate title for "why has xxx happened" on meta

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta, title

Often, there are questions about why (for example) a question was closed for a specific example, a edit was rejected, etc.  However, since users are unable to create questions with duplicate titles, this results in numerous random and tangentially related titles just to get around the filter, which doesn't aid others on meta and also clutters up search results.  Should there be some sort of mechanism to allow for these sorts of things on meta or would that be too much hassle and allow newbie "y wuz i baned" questions to pop up, further annoying the community?

Comment: I think that in general, posts titled like "why was my post closed?" could simply be retitled to be more specific (e.g. "why was my post about [X] closed?"). I'm not sure there's much of a benefit in letting titles on meta be identically generic.